# Mapping of key-values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary which looks as following:

```
{'items': [{'id': 1151, 'name': 'Sun'},
           {'id': 1152, 'name': 'Rain'},
           {'id': 1168, 'name': 'Clouds'},
           {'id': 1169, 'name': 'Clear'},
           {'id': 1170, 'name': 'Mist'},
           {'id': 1171, 'name': 'Fog'},
           {'id': 1231, 'name': 'Drizzle'}]}
```

Depending on the information about the weather given as 'Fog' or 'Drizzle' or whatever else, I should form a set:

```
info = {a: 0,
        'weather_id': 1170,
        'some parameter': 0,
        'vbla': None,
        'ff': some value}
```

where I should map the weather conditions. Currently I've just written an IF-Condition for each case which is of Course very stupid:

```
if weatherConditions=='Clouds':
   info = {a: 0,
            'weather_id': 1168,
            'some parameter': 0,
            'vbla': None,
            'ff': some value}
```

Could you please help me to solve my Problem?

Comment: Why is this stupid? Because you hardcoded "weather_id" instead of picking it from your dict?

Comment: yes. There is a possibility that some additional weather-value will appear.

Answer (score 2):

You could use "Sun", "Rain", "Clouds" etc. as key values and have a nested dictionary. Might get messy but it would do what you need it to

Answer (score 2):

Change your `dict` so the key is `name` and the `id` is the value and it will be much easier (assuming the weather `name` will never have duplicates):

```
def get_weather_info(new_dic, weather):
    if weather in new_dic:
        return {
          'a': 0,
          'weather_id': new_dic[weather],
          'some parameter': 0,
          'vbla': None,
          'ff': None
        }
d = {'items': [{'id': 1151, 'name': 'Sun'},
           {'id': 1152, 'name': 'Rain'},
           {'id': 1168, 'name': 'Clouds'},
           {'id': 1169, 'name': 'Clear'},
           {'id': 1170, 'name': 'Mist'},
           {'id': 1171, 'name': 'Fog'},
           {'id': 1231, 'name': 'Drizzle'}]}
new_dic = {dic['name']: dic['id'] for dic in d['items']}
info = get_weather_info(new_dic, 'Rain')
print(info)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your challenge is to extract the right id corresponding to the value of 'weatherConditions' variable. Here is how you can do it by cycling through the dictionary structure you have outlined and pull out the id corresponding to it (you will have to then map it to the right set of extra variables you want to include in your set):

```
my_dict = {'items': [{'id': 1151, 'name': 'Sun'},
       {'id': 1152, 'name': 'Rain'},
       {'id': 1168, 'name': 'Clouds'},
       {'id': 1169, 'name': 'Clear'},
       {'id': 1170, 'name': 'Mist'},
       {'id': 1171, 'name': 'Fog'},
       {'id': 1231, 'name': 'Drizzle'}]}



weatherConditions='Clouds'

for x in range(len(my_dict['items'])):
    if weatherConditions == my_dict['items'][x]['name']:
        print(my_dict['items'][x]['id'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!